# Does JavaScript stop working after a TypeError (Null)?

Tags: javascript

When I try to update CSS using DOM and JavaScript using the following code:

```
var el = document.querySelector('li.hodt'); //it should be 'li.hot'
el.className = 'cool';

var els = document.querySelectorAll('li.hot');
els[1].className = 'cool';
```

I made a typo intentionally to see what happens. As the first line contains a typo and there is no 'li.hodt' class, the variable el seems to be 'Null' (from the debugger). Obviously, el.className line would fail because el isn't a node.

But then I expected JS to keep moving forward and execute the second block of code, but somehow JS stops running after that error in the first block of code. According to Debugger (of FireFox) the two error messages are: TypeError & el is Null.

Does anyone know why this is so? Any design philosophy / stability reasons / whatever reasons behind this?

Thank you so much for your time and sharing your knowledge in advance.

Cheers

Comment: You can’t assign anything to `null`, it throws an error. Errors stop the code from executing. That’s pretty much the same in all languages. Usually that’s good, because it forces you to fix the error instead of having the code continue in an undefined state.

Comment: If you hit an NPE your program is now left in an undefined state. There is no guarantee of any sort of correctness if you continue the execution and silently ignoring the error is very likely to cause weird behaviour that is very hard to find and diagnose.

Answer (score 3):

> But then I expected JS to keep moving forward...

No, the error is thrown as an *exception*, it terminates the function call immediately (or if the code is at global scope, it stops executing global code at that point).

You can catch exceptions via a `try`/`catch` block if you want to do something that may throw and then keep going:

```
try {
    var el = document.querySelector('li.hodt'); //it should be 'li.hot'
    el.className = 'cool';
} catch (e) {
    // `e` contains the error information
}

var els = document.querySelectorAll('li.hot');
els[1].className = 'cool';
```

Since the `catch` "handles" the exception, the code following the `try`/`catch` runs. (Of course, if the code in the `catch` *also* throws, and nothing catches, execution terminates at that point.)

It's important to understand that this just affects the running job. If you have event handlers (or other callbacks) set up before the exception is thrown, they'll still be run when appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

When a runtime error occurs, *all* synchronous Javascript that you would expect to occur immediately after it will not run, *unless* the error occurs in a `try` block. Eg:

```
const foo = () => {
  bar();
  baz();
};
const bar = () => {
  // do something
  throw new Error();
  // do something else
};
```

Here, since `bar` throws, `do something` will run, but `do something else` will not, nor will the `baz` function.

If the thrown error occurs asynchronously, other parts of the code can continue to run. For example:

```
const foo = () => {
  Promise.resolve().then(bar);
  Promise.resolve().then(baz);
};
const bar = () => {
  // do something
  throw new Error();
  // do something else
};
```

Here, `bar` runs asynchronously, and isn't really connected to anything else, so even if it throws an error, `baz` will be able to run.

If a synchronous error is thrown inside a `try` block, control flow will return to the corresponding `catch` block, and code after that `catch` block will continue executing as normal.